# Font.loadAsync unsafe assignment of an any value on imported fonts

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm trying to import some fonts with using the Font.loadAsync but I'm getting this error:

`Unsafe assignment of an 'any' value`

[image]

Dependencies on my package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "expo-cli": "^5.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

My question is how can I define the type of these imports? I already made a font.d.ts file to define *.otf, but I still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I found the type of these imports is `FontSource` and all I did was declare this type in the d.ts I made for the fonts like this:

```js
declare module '*.otf' {
    import { FontSource } from 'expo-font';
    const value: FontSource;
    export default value;
}
```

Also I changed the import method to this

```js
import quicksandRegular from 'assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book.otf';
import quicksandBold from 'assets/fonts/Quicksand_Bold.otf';
import quicksandLight from 'assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light.otf';

function loadFonts() {
    return Font.loadAsync({
        'quicksand-regular': quicksandRegular,
        'quicksand-bold': quicksandBold,
        'quicksand-light': quicksandLight,
    });
}
```

This means that all .otf import I made using the ES6 syntax is getting the definition of my fonts.d.ts